# Dropdown List will not populate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure how to correct the following problem. I have dropdown list that has a object data source. Then in the code there is a method like this

```
void InitPageData()
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter da = new DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter();
    DataSet.MemberInfoDataTable dt = da.GetMember((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataSet.MemberInfoRow mr = dt[0];
        //rank.Text = mr.rank;
        //position.Text = mr.position;

        UserName.Text = user.UserName;
        ...
    }
```

This method populates form fields on the page. What I'm trying to do is to have the rank dropdown list populated from the ods but use this method above to populate the selected item of the rank dropwon list with the line rank.Text = mr.rank. In this example the the line of code that throws the error is commented out otherwise it throws this: "'rank' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value".

I've chaned the code to rank.DataTextFiled = mr.rank and rank.DataValueField = mr.rankid.ToString() but this threw another error: "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Star'." "Star" is the value of the mr.rank.

Here is what the dropdown list and the ods look like:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="rank" CssClass="txtfield" DataSourceID="ODCRanks"
    DataTextField="Rank" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
<asp:ListItem Text="--- Select a Rank ---" Value="-1"   />
```

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODCRanks" runat="server" 
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetRanks" 
TypeName="RanksTableAdapters.RankTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding data columns to your data tables (with ID and Rank being the column name) so that the data can be binded to control.

Comment: agian, not sure what you mean. ID and rank are columns in the db but I'm guessing that is not what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

The Text property sets it by value.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx

You seem to have what will be the text associated with the value and you want to set that as the selected item. I guess this mostly because your value collection is bound to something called ID and I figure a rank of Star isn't an ID.

If Star is what will show up as something in DataTextField, use the items collection FindByText method to select it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext.aspx

Example

```
    ListItem li = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("one");
    if (li != null) li.Selected = true;
```

If Star is indeed an ID, then check that the collection is fully loaded before trying to select anything in it.

Comment: I've tried that too (rank.selectedItem = mr.rank) errors out with "... cannot be assigned - read only value". The links you suggested don't really mean too much. Not sure how to associate that with what is going on in the code.

Comment: I didn't say to set SelectedItem. Is the dropdown list populating? If so, please view the source of the web page and post the HTML that was generated as a select element.

Comment: Here is ddl from the html: <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rank" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rank" class="txtfield">
 <option value="-1">--- Select a Rank ---</option>
 <option value="1"> </option>
 <option value="2">Scout</option>
 <option value="3">Tanderfoot</option>
 <option value="4">2nd Class</option>
 <option value="5">1st Class</option>
 <option value="6">Star</option>
 <option value="7">Life</option>
 <option value="8">Eagle</option>

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
rank.SelectedIndex = rank.Items.IndexOf(rank.Items.FindByText(mr.rank));
```

Comment: I've tried that, got "The value for column 'rank' in table 'MemberInfo' is DBNull."

Comment: well there's your answer :) you can't use something that's null to populate the selected item of the rank dropdown